# How can I get private key from metamask when sending a transaction?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

I am using `web3` to send a transaction to smart contract in ethereum network. `web3` library has a method

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey [, callback]);
```

to sign a transaction but it requires a private key. I wonder how I can get the private key? I assume it should bring up the metamask to ask users approval before signing the transaction. But I don't know how this flow work. Does anyone have a way to make it work?

Comment: You can export the private key using MetaMask: https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015289632-How-to-export-an-account-s-private-key. But, always follow the best practices to **hide your private key** in terms of never using it (as it is) anywhere in your codebase and always [encrypting](https://npm.io/search/keyword:.env.enc) it before using it as an environment variable.

Comment: is it the right way to do? If I publish the web3 website, it will be used by many users. I don't want to let each customer export the private key

Comment: In case of a web3 website (or a **dApp**, in general), the users will interact with it using their wallets (like MetaMask) that they connect to the website. The wallet connection and interactions are facilitated by `window.ethereum` object of the browser. You can read more about that from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152933/12726798.

Comment: yep, I know there is a `ethereum` instance. the question is how to use it to sign a transaction. It should open metamask but not sure how to trigger it

Comment: Basically, by passing `window.ethereum`, you can create a provider similar to what you create using json rpc, like: `provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);`. And then, you can get the `signer` from this, in order to pop-up the wallet to sign transactions, like: `const signer = provider.getSigner();`.

Comment: If that's still confusing for you, then I'll provide a sample code in HTML with two buttons, one for connecting metamask and other for signing a transaction corresponding to a sample contract function call, in the answer.

Comment: I can call getSigner. but the problem is how to get the private key to sign the transaction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152175/discussion-between-syed-asad-kazmi-and-joey-yi-zhao).